# .NET MAUI Blazor spellcheck for languages other than English

Tags: blazor, maui

I'm building an app with MAUI Blazor and can't find how to make my app underline misspelled non-English words in text editors. I´ve English, Spanish and Russian installed and configured to spellcheck words in said languages on my PC.
However, I get misspelled words of non-English languages underlined in other apps (e.g. Microsoft Edge) and my another WinUI 3 app.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: isn't this a feature of the browser, not the app itself?

Comment: could be a feature of the browser, idk. Is there a way to get the same functionality in my app?

Comment: Probably.  There are a wide variety of spellcheck APIs and plugins for .NET

Comment: Could you give me a link to such a plugin?